# How to make part of a table row clickable with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, playframework

I want all but the last `<td>` element in each table row to be one clickable unit.
Here is what I have:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dashboard-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Open Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for(ach_case <- caseList) {
            <tr>
                <div class="clickable-row">
                    <td>@ach_case.formatDate(ach_case.dateCreated)</td>
                    <td>@ach_case.name</td>
                </div>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-warning btn-action"
                        onclick="window.location='@routes.CaseController.editCase(ach_case.id)';"></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickable-row').click(function() {
        console.log("Row clicked");
    });
});
```

This doesn't do anything.  I'm very tired so hopefully this is just a simple problem.

Comment: try tr .clickable-row in selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code a bit to demonstrate - adding an alert instead of the console.log, but one way to do it is to add a class of clickable to each `<td>` except for the last one that houses the button. You could add the clickable class to the `<tr>`, but you still have to prevent the effect on the last `<td>` of each `<tr>` - better just to add the clickable class to the `<td>`'s that you want to include rather than adding it to the entire row and excluding the last `<td>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickable').click(function() {
        alert("Row clicked");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dashboard-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Open Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   
            <tr >
                    <td class="clickable">test</td>
                    <td class="clickable">test</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-warning btn-action"
                        onclick="window.location='@routes.CaseController.editCase(ach_case.id)';">test</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am also using an html data attribute associated with the clickable data and this is the only solution I was able to get to work that still ran nicely with it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `no-clickable` class to any table cell you want not to be clickable:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'tr:not(.no-clickable)', function() {
   alert('clicked!');
});
```

```css
tr:not(.no-clickable) th,
tr:not(.no-clickable) td { cursor:pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>1</th><td>Clickable row</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>Clickable row</td></tr>
    <tr><th>3</th><td>Clickable row</td></tr>
    <tr><th>4</th><td>Clickable row</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>Clickable row</td></tr>
    <tr class="no-clickable"><th>6</th><td>No clickable row</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**NOTE**

You can not place a div element right after a tr element. Instead place anything you want inside td or th elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```js
$(document).on('click', 'tr:not(tr:last-child)', function() {
   alert('clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>1</th><td>Clickable row</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>Clickable row</td></tr>
    <tr><th>3</th><td>Clickable row</td></tr>
    <tr><th>4</th><td>Clickable row</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>Clickable row</td></tr>
    <tr><th>6</th><td>No clickable row</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```